# First name should randomly match with other FIRST name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

All first name should randomly match with each other and when I tried to run query again the First Name should be match with others name. Not the match with FIRST time match.

For example I have 6 records in one table ...

First name column looks like:

```
JHON
LEE
SAM
HARRY
JIM
KRUK
```

So I want result like

```
First name1 First name2
Jhon.       Harry
LEE.        KRUK
HARRY       SAM
```

Comment: How random do you want?

Comment: One way but probably not what you really want: `with data as (select *, row_number() over (order by FN) as rn from T) select * from data as t1 inner join data t2 on t2.rn / 2 = t1.rn / 2 and t1.rn % 2 = 0 and t2.rn % 2 = 1`

Comment: What if the table has 7 rows? What if there are duplicates?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution is to first randomly sort the records, then calculate the grouping and a sequence number within the group and then finally select out the groups as rows.

You can follow along with the logic in this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/9JlK59w4

```
DECLARE @Sorted TABLE
(
  Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  FirstName varchar(30),
  RowNum INT IDENTITY(1,1) 
);
INSERT INTO @Sorted (Id, FirstName)
SELECT Id, FirstName
FROM People 
ORDER BY NEWID();
  
WITH Pairs as
(
    SELECT * 
         , (RowNum+1)/2 as PairNum
         , RowNum % 2 as Ordinal
    FROM @Sorted 
)
SELECT 
  Person1.FirstName as [First name1], Person2.FirstName as [First name2]
FROM Pairs Person1
LEFT JOIN Pairs Person2 ON Person1.PairNum = Person2.PairNum AND Person2.Ordinal = 1
WHERE Person1.Ordinal = 0
ORDER BY Person1.PairNum
```

- `ORDER BY NEWID()` is used here to randomly sort the records. Note that it is indeterminate and will return a new value with each execution. It's not very efficient, but is suitable for our requirement.

  > You can't easily use CTE's for producing lists of randomly sorted records because the result of a CTE is *not* cached. Each time the CTE is referenced in the subsequent logic can result in re-evaluating the expression. Run this fiddle a few times and watch how it often allocates the names incorrectly: https://dbfiddle.uk/rpPdkkAG

  Due to the volatility of `NEWID()` this example stores the results in a table valued variable. For a very large list of records a *temporary table* might be more efficient.
- `PairNum` uses the simple *divide by n* logic to assign a group number with a length of *n*

  - *It is necessary to add 1 to the `RowNum` because the integer math will round down, **see this in action in the fiddle.***
- `Ordinal` uses the modulo on the RowNumber and is a value we can use to differentiate between *Person 1* and *Person 2* in the pair. This helps us keep the rest of the logic determinate.

In the final `SELECT` we select first from the `Pairs` that have an `Ordinal` of `0`, then we join on the `Pairs` that have an `Ordinal` of `1` matching by the `PairNum`

---

You can see in the fiddle I added a solution using groups of 3 to show how this can be easily extended to larger groupings.

Comment: Please mark this as the answer, or let me know if there is anything missing or that you are unsure about.